# What's the difference between Yagna Varaha and Shwetha Varaha?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, varaha, sankalpa

I've been hearing that the Lord Varaha is being referred to as Yagna Varaha swamy while we say Shwetha Varaha name in Sankalpam. I'd like to know the difference.